# Python: Matrix w/ Sequential Values

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, sequential

I need to do the following:

1. Create a variable result as an array of length m.
2. For each row i from 0 to m-1:

   a. Set result[i] to a new array of length n.

   b. For each column j in row i, set that element to (i*n)+j.
3. When you’ve computed all the elements, return result.

So far, I have the following:

```
     def f2(m, n):
         result = [""] * m
         for i in range(0, m):
             result[i] = [""] * n   
         for i in result:
             for j in i:
                 result.append(i*n+j)
         return result
```

This, however, just results in an error.

Any help/suggestions? Thank you

Comment: What error does it result in? Post the full traceback.

Comment: Do you actually need to do the sequence of things you've listed, or do you simply need to produce an m-by-n nested list whose elements are the integers from 0 to m*n, in sequence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
def f2(m, n):
    #First, let's create a list with the size of m, and
    #each row with the size of n.
    result = [[0 for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(m)]
    #now, you can loop through it easily.
    for i in range(m): #outer list
         for j in range(n): #inner list
             result[i][j] = i*n+j #put it there :)
    return result
```

Hope this helsp!

Comment: `TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()`

Comment: @KDawG Whoops, fixed.

Comment: You have the variables `m` and `n`. Why the awkward range-len?

Comment: @user2357112 You've got a point.. Hahaha sorry, i'll change that.

Answer (score 1):

Use list [comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
def f2(m, n):
    return [[i*n+j for j in range(n)] for i in range(m)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in result:
    for j in i:
```

In this nested loop, `i` iterates over the rows of `result` and `j` iterates over the cell contents. Thus, in the loop body:

```
        result.append(i*n+j)
```

this line attempts to multiply a row by `n`, add `j` (a string) to that, and append the output of that to `result`. No part of that is what you want to do. You could fix this by iterating over the indices and assigning to elements instead of appending:

```
for i in range(m):
    for j in range(n):
        result[i][j] = i*n+j
```

but it's easier to build the whole array the way you want it with `range` instead of initializing it with garbage and assigning the elements:

```
def f2(m, n):
    return [range(n*i, n*i+n) for i in xrange(m)]
```

or if you're on Python 3:

```
def f2(m, n):
    return [list(range(n*i, n*i+n)) for i in range(m)]
```

or if list comprehensions are strange and unreadable to you:

```
def f2(m, n):
    result = []
    for i in range(m):
        result.append(list(range(n*i, n*i+n)))
    return result
```